# PHP text boxes dynamic ID generating

Tags: javascript

i would be very thankful if anyone could help me with this

i am  trying to use php uploader plugin and upload multiple files. 
i want to assign unique ids to the generating text box fields. 
but whenever I am using a for loop to assign id , the text boxes won't show up 
here is my code

```
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.value = task.FileName;
    input.id = "textBox_"; 

    for(var i = 0; i<0; i++){
    input.id = "textBox_'.i.'"; 

}
    document.body.appendChild(input);

}
```

the help will be appreciated ..

Comment: Well, it's pretty obvious that your quotation is broken, even stack overflow highlight sees it. And, concatenation in js is not made with `.`

Comment: it seems you're appending it outside the loop. Besides, your loop condition makes no sense. It never enters the loop. So you are not doing anything really. Besides, you should use `+` for the concatenation in JS.

Comment: Are you sure about this condition? `for(var i = 0; i<0; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

You are not appending the value of `i` properly. In js concatenation is done using `+` operator not using `.`

```
input.id = "textBox_"+i;
```

Place

```
 document.body.appendChild(input);
```

inside the `for` loop like shown below as it has to generate `input` each time until loop ends.

```
     for(var i = 0; i<0; i++)
     {
         input.id = "textBox_"+i; 
         document.body.appendChild(input);
    }
```

Comment: thx for your reply. but it still won't add an dynamic id generated by the for loop

Comment: @user3431701 take a look at your loop. It's not doing anything. The `i<0` condition should be something like `i<totalDocuments` and also your appending command should go inside the loop, not outside

Comment: @user3431701..On what condition you want to run this loop?

Comment: @DanieX2010  thx for your answer .
but after we put the  document.body.appendChild(input) inside the 
for loop. the auto generating text boxes won't show up ...

Comment: @Jenz 
i am using php file uploader plugin to upload mulitiple images. after that i want save them in database. for tht i have to generate the unique ids in the text boxes that auto generates after uploading files

Comment: @user3431701..What is the condition you are checking for..According to the current loop condition, it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Change `input.id = "textBox_'.i.'";` to `input.id = "textBox_"+i;`

Concatenation in js is cone using `+` operator
So your code will be:

```
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.value = task.FileName;
    input.id = "textBox_"; 

    for(var i = 0; i<0; i++){//Condition of this loop is wrong in the sence it wont execute even once so fix it as your needs
    input.id = "textBox_"+i;
    document.body.appendChild(input);

}
}
```

Comment: thx for your support .
but after we put the  document.body.appendChild(input) inside the 
for loop. the auto generating text boxes won't show up ...